# Detect scroll is completed with PointerWheelChanged

Tags: windows-8, windows-runtime, mouse, mousewheel

I detect mouse wheel scroll using `PointerWheelChanged` event at WinRT. I use `PointerPoint.Properties.MouseWheelDelta` to detect amount and direction of scroll:

```
PointerPoint mousePosition = e.GetCurrentPoint(_control);
var delta = mousePosition.Properties.MouseWheelDelta;
```

Nowadays there are devices which emulate mouse scroll (touchpad or touch mice etc).
They tend to issue tens or hundreds (sic!) `PointerWheelChanged` events per "scroll". Legacy mouse wheel issues one event per wheel click which has delta of +-120 units.

I need to do some heavy processing as soon as user scrolls to some position.

Is there a way to understand that "new" scroll is complete?

FYI Here is a mouse wheel deltas for a single finger flick with Microsoft TouchMouse (sorry for the amount, I just want to illustrate the problem).

15
15
164
164
304
304
658
658
773
773
887
887
1000
1000
1111
1111
1221
1221
1330
1330
108
108
107
107
106
106
105
105
104
104
103
103
102
102
203
203
100
100
99
99
98
98
97
97
96
96
95
95
94
94
93
93
92
92
91
91
90
90
89
89
88
88
88
88
87
87
86
86
85
85
84
84
83
83
82
82
82
82
81
81
80
80
79
79
78
78
78
78
77
77
76
76
75
75
75
75
74
74
73
73
72
72
72
72
71
71
70
70
70
70
69
69
68
68
67
67
67
67
66
66
65
65
65
65
64
64
63
63
63
63
62
62
62
62
61
61
60
60
60
60
59
59
59
59
58
58
57
57
57
57
56
56
56
56
55
55
55
55
54
54
54
54
53
53
52
52
52
52
51
51
51
51
50
50
50
50
49
49
49
49
48
48
48
48
47
47
47
47
46
46
46
46
46
46
45
45
45
45
44
44
44
44
43
43
43
43
42
42
42
42
42
42
41
41
41
41
40
40
40
40
40
40
39
39
39
39
38
38
38
38
38
38
37
37
37
37
37
37
36
36
36
36
35
35
35
35
35
35
34
34
34
34
34
34
33
33
33
33
33
33
32
32
32
32
32
32
31
31
31
31
31
31
30
30
30
30
30
30
30
30
29
29
29
29
29
29
28
28
28
28
28
28
28
28
27
27
27
27
27
27
26
26
26
26
26
26
26
26
25
25
25
25
25
25
25
25
24
24
24
24
24
24
24
24
23
23
23
23
23
23
23
23
23
23
22
22
22
22
22
22
22
22
21
21
21
21
21
21
21
21
21
21
20
20
20
20
20
20
20
20
20
20
19
19
19
19
19
19
19
19
19
19
18
18
18
18
18
18
18
18
18
18
18
18
17
17
17
17
17
17
17
17
17
17
17
17
16
16
16
16
16
16
16
16
16
16
16
16
15
15
15
15
15
15
15
15
15
15
15
15
14
14
14
14
14
14
14
14
14
14
14
14
14
14
14
14
13
13
13
13
13
13
13
13
13
13
13
13
13
13
12
12
12
12
12
12
12
12
12
12
12
12
12
12
12
12
12
12
11
11
11
11
11
11
11
11
11
11
11
11
11
11
11
11
11
11
10
10
10
10
10
10
10
10
10
10
10
10
10
10
10
10
10
10
10
10
9
9
9
9
9
9
9
9
9
9
9
9
9
9
9
9
9
9
9
9
9
9
8
8
8
8
8
8
8
8
8
8
8
8
8
8
8
8
8
8
8
8
8
8
8
8
15
15
22
22
7
7
7
7
14
14
7
7
7
7
7
7
7
7
7
7
7
7
7
7
7
7
6
6
6
6
6
6
6
6
6
6
6
6
6
6
6
6
6
6
6
6
6
6
6
6
6
6
6
6
6
6
6
6
6
6
5
5
5
5
5
5
5
5
5
5
5
5
5
5
5
5
5
5
5
5
5
5
5
5
5
5
5
5
5
5
5
5
5
5
5
5
5
5
5
5
4
4
4
4
4
4
4
4
4
4
4
4
4
4
4
4
4
4
4
4
4
4
4
4
4
4
4
4
4
4
4
4
4
4
4
4
4
4
4
4
4
4
4
4
4
4
8
8
12
12
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
9
9
3
3
3
3
3
3
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1

EDIT:
Now I do this hack but it is far from perfect

```
// interval between mouse deltas
private readonly TimeSpan _wheelDeltaThrottleInterval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(8);

// interval to wait until scroll is complete
private readonly TimeSpan _wheelDeltaCompleteInterval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(600);

// create smart wheel handler
IObservable<PointerPoint> pointerWheelObservable = 
    System.Reactive.Linq.Observable
        .FromEventPattern<PointerEventHandler, PointerRoutedEventArgs>(
            handler => _control.PointerWheelChanged += handler,
            handler => _control.PointerWheelChanged -= handler)
        .Select(eventPattern =>
            {
                PointerRoutedEventArgs e = eventPattern.EventArgs;
                PointerPoint mousePosition = e.GetCurrentPoint(_control);
                return mousePosition;
            })
        .Where(mousePosition => Math.Abs(mousePosition.Properties.MouseWheelDelta) > MouseWheelDeltaThreshold);

// subscribe to wheel changes
pointerWheelObservable
    .Throttle(_wheelDeltaThrottleInterval)
    .ObserveOnDispatcher()
    .Subscribe(
        OnPointerWheelChanged,
        Logger.TrackException);

pointerWheelObservable
    .Throttle(_wheelDeltaCompleteInterval)
    .Subscribe(
        OnPointerWheelCompleted,
        Logger.TrackException);
```

---

EDIT2 `GestureRecognizer` class does not help

See this great blog post regarding Windws 8 manipulations handling.
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsappdev/archive/2012/07/02/modernizing-input-in-windows-8.aspx

Unfortunately after my experiments I see `GestureRecognizer` is not able to detect mouse wheel events *flood* is over. It fires ManipulationCompleted event after each call of .ProcessMouseWheelEvent()

Comment: What are you using this for? You say you want to do some processing when the user scrolls to some position, in a list, or? If that's the case, I think it would be easier to detect the scrolled position on the list instead of the mouse/pad...

Comment: User is zooming in or out our own map implementation

Answer (score 1):

You can use Reactive Extension library and [throttle](http://rxwiki.wikidot.com/101samples#toc29) on the WheelChangedEvent, that way you would always get the last notification for the specified throttle time period

Comment: A already do that Throttle thing, but it is not perfect.
It is a hack in general

Comment: But what other technique can we use? Flipping a wheel is a computer generated event, the source is dynamic, as your operation is expensive, you would want to delay as much as possible via throttling.

Comment: Throttling is no good because when scroll is complete user has to wait a second to have my operation started.
If there is a way to determine that mouse has completed scroll I'd be happy

Comment: You don't have to throttle to a second - with what you are describing possibly waiting for 0.05s would likely be enough and no one would notice a delay.

Comment: Unfortunately scroll events come with increased interval in the end. I cannot do my operation until scroll is finished for sure.

Answer (score 1):

Use GestureRecognizer for a better low level detection of manipulations including mouse whell.
All inputs (mouse, touch, pen, etc.) are included here and supported better than traditional manipulation events. (they don't support single touch rotation, mouse scroller, etc.)

http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Input-Windows-8-gestures-62c6689b#content

This is much more efficient, flexible and safer than implementing everything from scratch.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Your message has led me to reading this helpful blog post from Microsoft:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsappdev/archive/2012/07/02/modernizing-input-in-windows-8.aspx

Comment: Unfortunately cool GestureRecognizer does not solve my problem with LOTS of scroll evens coming from those touch panels. Looks like I have to stay with Throttle code for now