# Smooth zoom in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, zooming, mousewheel

So here is my questions that I hope I will be able to ask it in a proper way.

**In brief:** how to zoom smoothly in WPF?

**In detail:** I'm writing a CAD application in WPF that I'm redrawing parts of the screen when `MouseWheel` event is fired.

```
private void ModelWindowBorder_MouseWheel(object sender, MouseWheelEventArgs e)
{
       var zoom = e.Delta > 0 ? 0.2 : -0.2;
    // increase or decrease the scale by *zoom*
    // Redraw Screen
    // Apply TransformScale and etc.
}
```

Well actually the above code works but I'm not content with it for two reasons:

1. When I have to redraw lots of visuals on the screen it kinda misses the multiple `MouseWheel` events that are fired. So if 8 MouseWheel events are to be fired in **one big scroll** only 4-5 of them are fired. And this makes the zooming a little slow.
2. The second reason might not be WPF related at all. Is `var zoom = e.Delta > 0 ? 0.2 : -0.2;` the correct way we should increase/decrease the scale? To me it seems not appropriate. Since when we are zoomed out the difference seems considerable when we zoom in by one step, but once we are close to the drawing, increasing the zoom by one step doesn't seem much.

I'd like to know your answers and comments on both of these issues.

Comment: Unless you show us what you actually do with the `zoom` variable, it's hard to answer the second question.

Comment: @Clemens I'm actually adding it to ScaleX/ScaleY property of the `ScaleTransform` like this `st.ScaleX += zoom;`

Comment: You might instead multiply or divide by some factor like `1.2`.

Comment: Yes, I think I should work on that, it gave me unexpected results in the first try though.

Comment: I got this working to an extent. @Clemens do you have any suggestions regarding the first issue?

Comment: @Sinatr Can you post the pseudo-code as an answer?

Comment: Screw my comment. You are not only have to check positive or negative delta, but also **value** of it, it may get combined into bigger number if multiple wheel events can't reach UI thread in time: `st.ScaleX *= e.Delta / k;`, where `k` is some `double` factor.

Comment: @Sinatr Thanks, I actually changed to this based on Clemens's comment. My first issue remains.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Problem 1.

You should take in account the **value** of `e.Delta`.

Not

```
var zoom = e.Delta > 0 ? 0.2 : -0.2;
```

but

```
var zoom = e.Delta * k;
```

`k` is a `double` factor, it's *device* [specific](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.mousewheeleventargs.delta.aspx)

> The effective upper and lower ranges of this value potentially come from device implementations or other callers that raised the event, and are therefore not defined

But its value get **higher** for as you say *one big scroll*.

One possible solution to find `k` would be to get first `MouseWheel` event and use received value as a starting point. If you receive double of that value, then two or more of mousewheel scrolls were combined into single event. Or do calibration all time, remembering smallest value and changing factor for it. Up to you.

### Problem 2.

Use multiplication instead of adding flat value.

And combined solution will looks like this

```
st.ScaleX *= e.Delta * k;
```

Comment: Thanks Sinatr, I guess I'm seeing a hope. You mean for the first problem I should wait for the scroll to finish then based on the input received I should redraw and scale the screen? I'm kinda lost here.

Comment: I just need to implement a way that the number of `MouseWheel` events in each big scroll doesn't get affected by the redrawing process. I just don't know how to do it.

Comment: Wow Sinatr, this is genius, Now I figured out what you meant! This is amazing. I wish I could give you all my points! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

One simple thing to try and coelesce MouseWheel events is to use Rx. You can use the .FromEventPattern() method to consume Wheel events and only care about those that satisfy your delta tolerances. Rx is a little tricky but can help you have simpler code paths.

See this answer - [Detect scroll is completed with PointerWheelChanged](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13816352/detect-scroll-is-completed-with-pointerwheelchanged)

Comment: Thanks adamhill, I will look into it now.